# Progress Bar while sending ByteArray to Server through Action Method in MVC 3

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc

I have a byte-array that i upload to the server through action method from javascript (MVC3):

```
      $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("Upload")',
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/x-amf',
        processData: false,
        data: ByteArrayData,
        success: function (result) {
            alert(result);
        }

    });
```

I was wondering what is the easiest way to make a percentage progress bar while the bytes are getting sent to the server?

Comment: do you want Indeterministic/deterministic progress bar. a loading animation or a percentage you want?

Comment: percentage bar which means its deterministic i guess

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way would be to Mask the content using javascript or show Javascript progress bar on view, until you get the response back from Server.

Comment: sorry for the confusion, i want a deterministic percentage progress bar.

Answer (score 1):

My initial (and boring) response is that this would be hard to do, but I'm not wise enough with the HTTP post request to completely be sure if it is or isn't possible. Essentially though you'd have to either know:

- Size of posted data
- Upload speed

OR

- Size of posted data
- Data sent each interval (if such a thing even exists?)

I'm not sure you can access either of these combinations with JavaScript. You'd probably need to use some sort of flash uploader for this.